Do Fruits of Israel (dates grown and packed in Israel) require or have a special blessing?
Do Fruits of Israel (organic King Solomon dates grown and packed in Israel in Kibbuz Ne´ot Smadar, bought in German Alnatura store in Germany) require or have a special blessing?
Thanks

Kibbutz Neot Smadar is probably not in the halachic Land of Israel, so its produce would be no different from local German products

B Berachot 43a

אֲמַר לֵיהּ רַב חִסְדָּא לְרַב יִצְחָק: הַאי מִשְׁחָא דַאֲפַרְסְמוֹן מַאי מְבָרְכִין עִלָּוֵיהּ? אָמַר לֵיהּ, הָכִי אָמַר רַב יְהוּדָה: "בּוֹרֵא שֶׁמֶן אַרְצֵנוּ". אָמַר לֵיהּ: בַּר מִינֵּיהּ דְּרַב יְהוּדָה דַּחֲבִיבָא לֵיהּ אֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל, לְכוּלֵּי עָלְמָא מַאי? אָמַר לֵיהּ: הָכִי אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן: "בּוֹרֵא שֶׁמֶן עָרֵב".
Rav Ḥisda said to Rav Yitzḥak: This balsam oil, what blessing does one recite over it? Rav Yitzḥak said to him, this is what Rav Yehuda said: One recites: Who creates the oil of our land, as balsam only grew in Eretz Yisrael, in the Jordan valley. Rav Ḥisda said to him: Except for Rav Yehuda, for whom Eretz Yisrael was extremely beloved and who therefore mentioned it in his blessing, what blessing does everyone else recite over balsam oil? He said to him: This is what Rabbi Yoḥanan said: One recites: Who creates pleasant oil.


https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.44a.16?lang=bi&with=all

This distinction is in ברכה מעין שלש
